# Angular Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. Ng For only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

Dears i have this error while trying to use Data table of angular 4 component 
My json is like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "objectLevelCode": "Customer", 
    "objectNumber": "11110123211", 
    "objectName": "tom ", 
    "customerJoiningDate": "2014/3/10 12:17:00",
    "politicallyExposed": true, 
    "alertCount": 3, 
    "transactionsCount": 3, 
    "totalTransactionsAmount": "3000 EGP", 
    "oldestAlert": "2016/3/20", 
    "createdOn": "2016/3/28", 
    "riskClassificationCode": "High", 
    "moneyLaunderingScore": 1, 
    "complianceUserId": "michel", 
    "naturalId": "PTY.1"
  }
]
```

and my ts file is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";    
import {alarm} from "../shared/alarm.model";
import { DataTableResource } from 'angular-4-data-table';

@Component({
selector: 'app-alarm-data-table',
providers:[],
templateUrl: './alarm-data-table.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./alarm-data-table.component.css']
})
export class AlarmDataTableComponent implements OnInit {

alarmsData = new DataTableResource(this.alarmsData);
alarmCount:number =0;
constructor( private http: HttpClient) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<alarm[]>('http:my api ').
    subscribe(data => {this.alarmsData = data ; this.alarmCount =data.length ;}
    , error2 => {console.log('Error has occured');
    });
}
}
```

And in html I used data table tag with datatable component in Angular.

Please can anyone tell me what should I do ? 
      My Html

```
 </data-table-column>
 <data-table-column
  [property]="'naturalId'"
  [header]="'Natural'"
  [sortable]="true"
  [resizable]="true">
  </data-table-column>
   </data-table>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the html file contents as well please?

Comment: `*ngFor` can't iterate objects, only arrays

Comment: i dont use *ng for i used data table ??? @Gunter

Comment: `alarmsData = new DataTableResource(this.alarmsData);`. This makes no sense at all.

Comment: @JBNIzet what should it be ?

Comment: Then datatable uses `*ngFor`. Just ensure the data you pass is an array.

Comment: all data has been appeared correctly but still have this error in console !!
i think if the data structure was wrong it can not appeared ??

Answer (score 0):

This error could be occurring before the http call is made to your API and data is fetched. This is because you are setting **alarmsData** to **new DataTableResource(this.alarmsData)** object, which is not an iterable. However, once the data is fetched from API, you are setting value of alarmsData as an array, in the line-

```
data => {this.alarmsData = data ; this.alarmCount =data.length ;} //Here, alarmsData is set as an array
```

So when alarmsData is set as an iterable(array), the data is rendered properly on table. This is why you could be getting that error message even though data is rendered correctly.

Try initialising alarmsData as an empty array-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";    
import {alarm} from "../shared/alarm.model";
import { DataTableResource } from 'angular-4-data-table';

@Component({
selector: 'app-alarm-data-table',
providers:[],
templateUrl: './alarm-data-table.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./alarm-data-table.component.css']
})
export class AlarmDataTableComponent implements OnInit {

//Initialize alarmsData to an empty array.
alarmsData = [];

alarmCount:number =0;
constructor( private http: HttpClient) {

}     
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<alarm[]>('http:my api ').
    subscribe(data => {this.alarmsData = data ; this.alarmCount =data.length ;}
    , error2 => {console.log('Error has occured');
    });
}
}
```

Source- https://github.com/MIt9/angular-4-data-table-demo/blob/master/src/app/demo1/data-table-demo1-remote.ts